# Javascript - How to make object stay directly in front of another one?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

I'm trying to code a mouth part which will stay directly at the front of a bitmap, but needs to be a separate object.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
   // LOCATION:
   var xDistance = stage.getStage().mouseX - player.x;
   var yDistance = stage.getStage().mouseY - player.y;
   var distance = Math.sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
   var x = player.x += xDistance * easingAmount;
   var y = player.y += yDistance * easingAmount;

   if (distance > 1) {
     player.x += xDistance * easingAmount;
     player.y += yDistance * easingAmount;
   }

   // ROTATION:
   var degrees = (Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
   if(degrees >= 360) {
     degrees -= 360;
   }

   player.rotation = degrees;
   stage.update();
```

Obviously using the following code will place the x and y values of the mouth -50 in the direction of the player, but this only works for 1 direction instead of keeping the mouth in front of the player:

```
   mouth.x = player.x - 50;
   mouth.y = player.y - 50;
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this math? I would really appreciate it. Here are 2 images to better explain things:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you want exactly... Do you want the player to maintain a constant distance from the mouth and rotate with it?

Comment: What does this have to do with math?

Comment: @Ness Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for you, that will also help you in the future, is to first get a solid tested vector library to do all these calculations for you. For example, you can try this one http://victorjs.org/ which looks good (haven't tried it myself though).

Once you have vectors working, the algorithm is quite simple:

1. Get your player's direction as an angle or radian.
2. Create a vector from that angle.
3. Multiply that vector in your desired distance.
4. The position of the mouth, or the other part, is the position of the player + the vector.

With victorjs it would be something like this (not tested):

```
// who the hell calls his "Vector" class "Victor"? alias it.
var Vector = Victor;

// create the vector from player angle (assume player_angle is defined somewhere)
var v = new Vector(1, 0);
v = v.rotateDeg(player_angle);

// multiply by desired distance, assume its 20 pixels
v = v.multiply(new Vector(20, 20));

// now calc mouth position (assume player_pos is defined before)
var mouth_pos = player_pos.add(mouth_pos);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently using EaselJS to create bitmaps. The mouth part and player are both bitmaps that have been created with this library. If I already have all of these calculations, do I need VectorJS? Just a thought. I really appreciate your help though.

Comment: As you can see, I am using this line: var degrees = (Math.atan2(yDistance, xDistance) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90; to calculate the angle of the player. All I need to do is figure out how I can get the mouth part to accurately micmic the player, just a few pixels in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

@Ness's solution should work fine. However, if you want to avoid external dependencies the following could work. Define the mouth vector:

```
mouth.x = 50;
mouth.y = 0; // The mouth is the distance 50 away from the player.
             // Assuming that a non-rotated player points in the x-
             // direction
rotateVector(mouth, player.rotation);
```

And you can define the `rotateVector` as (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)))

```
function rotateVector(var vec, var degrees) {
    var output; // of vector type
    output.x = cos(degrees)*vec.x - sin(degrees)*vec.y;
    output.y = sin(degrees)*vec.x + cos(degrees)*vec.y;
    return output;
}
```

The world space position of the mouth is now

```
mouthWorldSpace = player.position + mouth.position; // (i.e. just add the vectors together)
```

This is the position that the mouth bitmap should be drawn.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. However, I think I already have these calculations. As I said to @Ness, I'm really just looking to make the mouth bitmap accurately mimic the behaviour of the player. Also, I already have an external dependency called EaselJS (should've probably mentioned this in OP).

Comment: @Skua Then I'm not really sure what the problem is (I added 3 lines that I realized I had missed -- is that what you are looking for?). This method should correctly give you the location of the mouth (which you can render as a bitmap or anything else)

Comment: Cheers - I'll give that a shot :)